Finding matching value from one flux while iterating over another
Suppose I have 2 fluxes:
Flux<TypeA> typeAFlux = ...
Flux<TypeB> typeBFlux = ...

And I can join typeAFlux w/ typeBFlux via typeAFlux.fieldA = typeAFlux.fieldB. How would I go about that while iterating over typeAFlux as such:
typeAFlux.map(ele -> {
  TypeB correspondTypeB = <Somehow get TypeB>; 
  ele.typeBRef = correspondingTypeB; 
  return ele;
})


Can you tell more what is the end goal? It looks like you have oversimplified the question and it would be ineffective if you apply the same to a real life scenario. Otherwise, If it's just to find a value, then use the filter method.

@IgorArtamonov Basically the end goal is I have 2 fluxes, and they are a one-to-many relationship (so in the above ex, TypeA is one-to-many with TypeB). I tried using filter, inside the map, but that also returned a flux and I wasn't sure how to proceed.

To get only one element (i.e., a Mono) from a Flux use the next() method.

But it's unlikely you could solve your problem with this approach. Because if you want to join two streams you have to have at least one fully loaded before (which makes it not a Flux), or it's unclear how you would traverse it. Also, to make it effective, you want at least one of them coming as sorted, which may also not work if you don't control the flux data.

You could do it in a reactive way if both are sorted.

If I understand correctly you want to match a Flux<TypeB> to elements of a Flux<TypeA> based on some criterion, correct?
For instance you'd have a Flux<Shoe> and a Flux<Colours> and you'd like to create a new Flux<ShoesWithColour>, where ShoesWithColour would hold a colour and every shoes having that colour, correct?
